# Basic Stack Exchange API usage

Tags: support, api

I would like to know what the example URL would be to retrieve answers from all Stack Exchange sites for a question.

For example, let's say I search for a question "how to oil a bicycle chain?". What is the URL to get answers from all Stack Exchange sites for this question?

Answer (score 1):

[Stack Exchange API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) lists all the methods available to you and each method has its own page with discussion on its usage and a handy little input to test out the method (which also generates the relevant request URL for you).

The [`/search`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search) method is used to search a specific site. There are also the [`/search/advanced`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search), [`/search/excerpts`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) and [`/similar`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/similar) methods for more advanced searches. But as far as I'm aware there is no way to search the entire network.

As a very basic example, the URL to search this site for this specific question is:

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?intitle=basic%20stack%20exchange%20api%20usage&site=meta